# How to enforce unique keys on CosmosDB using the unique key policy with the node sdk?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a CosmosDB container that uses a combination of property A and property B in order to determine an item's uniqueness. The partition key for the container is a guid in the "id" field. Recently, I ran into a race condition where it was adding two entries that had the same properties A and B but different IDs. I tried to fix this using the unique key policy in the node sdk as shown below:

```
export function getContainerDefinition(containerId: string) : ContainerDefinition
{
    let indexingPolicy : CompositeIndexingPolicy = {};
    let uniqueKeyPolicy: UniqueKeyPolicy = {
        uniqueKeys: []
    };
    if (containerId.includes("ab"))
    {
        const path : IndexedPath[] = [  { "path":"/a"}, { "path":"/b"} ];
        indexingPolicy = {
            compositeIndexes: [ path ]
        };
        uniqueKeyPolicy = {
            uniqueKeys: [
                { paths: ['/a', '/b'] }
            ]
        }
    }

    let partitionKey = { kind: "Hash", paths: ["/id"] };
    if (containerId.includes("user"))
    {
        partitionKey = { kind: "Hash", paths: ["/email"] };
    }

    return {
        id: containerId,
        partitionKey: partitionKey,
        indexingPolicy: indexingPolicy,
        uniqueKeyPolicy: uniqueKeyPolicy
    };
}
```

After the container gets created I went through my local Azure Cosmos DB Emulator and was able to add two entries with the same properties A and B but having different IDs. I'm unable to see the unique key policy in the settings so my only way to was to add a console.log before the container creation to be sure the policy was being applied correctly (which is was). Is there a way to enforce the unique keys such that I cannot add two items with different IDs with the same properties A and B?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Also I fixed this by making property A the partition key then added a unique key policy for properties A and B. Incase you want to add that to your answer.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is is that you are using `/id` as your Partition Key definition.

The Unique Key policy applies per partition key value (https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/unique-keys), which means that it checks that, within a partition key value, not 2 documents have the same value of said property/properties.

[image: Unique key description regarding value in partition key scope]